# Insertar objetos en memoria a una base de datos

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Estoy intentando guardar en base de datos, unos objetos que tengo en un arrayList, pero me da el siguiente error:

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [saveCampaign], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

Este es mi controlador:

```
@PostMapping("/saveCampaign")
public void save (@Validated DebtFileTO debtFileTO, Model model, Campaign campaign) {
    int positionCampaign = -1;
    int positionCustomer = -1;
    String rule1="Debt Age between 60-90";
    String rule2="Debt Age between > 120";
    for (int n = 0; n < listcampaigns.size(); n++) {
        if (listcampaigns.get(n).getDebtagerule()==rule1) {
            positionCampaign=n;
            campaign = listcampaigns.get(positionCampaign);
            if (positionCampaign!=-1) {
                for (int f = 0; f < debtFileTOSelected.size(); f++) {
                    if (debtFileTOSelected.get(f).getDebtage()>=60||debtFileTOSelected.get(f).getDebtage()<=90){
                        positionCustomer=f;
                        debtFileTO = debtFileTOs.get(positionCustomer);
                        if (positionCustomer!=-1) {
                            debtFileTO.setRemindebttype(campaign.getRemindebttype());
                            debtFileTO.setEvery(campaign.getEvery());
                            debtFileTO.setUnit(campaign.getUnit());
                            serviceDebtFileTo.save(debtFileTO);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Y asi es como estoy intentando hacer el insert en la base de datos desde mi archivo .html

```
<form th:action="@{/saveCampaign}" method="POST" th:object=${debtFileTO}>
                        <button style="position: sticky"  type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Guardar Campaña</button>
                    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No he podido replicar este error. Alguno de los métodos del controlador devuelve la vista 'saveCampaign.html'? Supongo que este método del que te hablo es el que renderiza el formulario que el usuario completa, por lo general un tipo GET.

Thymeleaf no lo está encontrando, bien sea por el nombre que puede no estar exactamente igual al del html, o porque este no se encuentra dentro del directorio Resources. Asegúrate de lo siguiente:

1. Se encuentra en directorio resources
2. El html se llama saveCampaign.html
3. El html tiene la estructura correcta que permite Thymeleaf:
   ver [esto](https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-hello-world-example-thymeleaf/#:%7E:text=%3C!DOCTYPE%20HTML%3E%0A%3Chtml%20lang%3D%22en%22%20xmlns%3Ath%3D%22http%3A//www.thymeleaf.org%22%3E%0A%3Chead%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cmeta%20charset%3D%22utf%2D8%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cmeta%20name%3D%22viewport%22%20content%3D%22width%3Ddevice%2Dwidth%2C%20initial%2Dscale%3D1%2C%20shrink%2Dto%2Dfit%3Dno%22%3E%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctitle%3ESpring%20Boot%20Thymeleaf%20Hello%20World%20Example%3C/title%3E%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%3Clink%20rel%3D%22stylesheet). Recuerda que cada tag debe tener etiqueta de cierre.
4. Como buena práctica, prueba que el método 'save' en lugar de que no retorne nada, que redireccione a la vista principal, por ejemplo:

   ```
    @PostMapping("/saveCampaign")
    public void save (@Validated DebtFileTO debtFileTO, Model model, 
      Campaign campaign) {
        //logica del método
        return "redirect:/index";
      }
   ```

Index o como se llame la vista principal.

5. Puedes ver este CRUD, quizás ayude:  https://github.com/Mikeb91/SpringMvc-Jpa